# How to add math library for gcc in docker Image?

Tags: 20.04, compiling, docker, gcc, lua

I am trying to containerize [LuaJIT](https://github.com/vkrasnov/bench_lua/tree/4eb69afd60cbc01ffaee9c61be24c3ddd6abad79), a derivative of Ubuntu image. I've installed build-essentials and I am getting the below compiler error saying that I am missing math library. There is already [-lm](https://github.com/vkrasnov/bench_lua/blob/4eb69afd60cbc01ffaee9c61be24c3ddd6abad79/Makefile#L11) option in the Makefile.

Can you please help me to fix this compilation error? Thank you

4eb69afd60
**Compilation errors**

```
gcc main.c -O3 -c -o main.o -I ./LuaJIT/src
gcc main.o -lpthread -lm  -ldl ./LuaJIT/src/libluajit.a -o bench
/usr/bin/ld: ./LuaJIT/src/libluajit.a(lj_vmmath.o): in function `lj_vm_foldarith':
lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `atan2'
/usr/bin/ld: ./LuaJIT/src/libluajit.a(lj_vmmath.o): in function `lj_vm_foldfpm':
lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x161): undefined reference to `cos'
/usr/bin/ld: lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x169): undefined reference to `tan'
/usr/bin/ld: lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `exp2'
/usr/bin/ld: lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to `log'
/usr/bin/ld: lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `log2'
/usr/bin/ld: lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x1c1): undefined reference to `log10'
/usr/bin/ld: lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x1c9): undefined reference to `sin'
/usr/bin/ld: lj_vmmath.c:(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to `sqrt'
```

I could build the project without any problem on the host.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update the package list
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y wget git vim make

RUN git clone https://github.com/vkrasnov/bench_lua.git && cd bench_lua && git checkout 4eb69afd60

WORKDIR /bench_lua
```

Comment: See [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: But I could build the same repo on host system.